# How to print Euro (€) character on an UTF-8 file?

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a `.php` file saved as `UTF-8` and I would like to let it print out a character like €

How can I do it?

This is the source code of the example:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

echo "€";
?>
```

The file was saved with `notepad++` as `UTF-8` but when I execute the file it just prints me out "?"

---

**Answer**

While the answer provided here [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) fullfills various aspect of UTF-8, i found the answer to my question inside [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310991/matthew) comment.

The .php file was saved as UTF-8 but WITH BOM. Within Notepad++ i choosed Format-> "UTF-8 without BOM" and the script worked.

Comment: This should work if the file is indeed encoded in UTF-8. Are you looking at this in a browser or on the command line?

Comment: Make sure that the file is saved as UTF8 wituout BOM : Copy the content of the file, open a new file encoded UTF8 w/o BOM, paste and save.

Comment: While the answer provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through fullfills various aspect of UTF-8, i found the answer to my question inside Matthew comment. The .php file was saved as UTF-8 but WITH BOM. With Notepad++ i choosed Format-> UTF-8 without BOM and the script worked.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Euro symbol in the file was actually entered as Windows-1252 or some other non-UTF-8 character set (encoding). How *exactly* did you type it in? Don't tell me that you copy and pasted it from a Word document!

For output to a browser, consider using `&euro;` instead -- guaranteed good. If it *must* be a hard coded binary multibyte character, you have to double check that you're actually editing in UTF-8 mode. I suspect that you aren't.